# JS filter method returns an empty array when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var test1 = [
  {
   id: 1
  },
  {
   id: 2
  },
  {
   id: 3
  },
];

var test2 = [
  {
   id: 3,
   text: 'some other text 3'
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   text: 'some other text 2'
  }
];

// filter method
function getNewArray(val) {
  test2.filter(function(val2){
    if(val.id == val2.id){
       return (val2.text);
       }
  });
}
var data1 =  test1.filter(getNewArray);

console.log(data1);
```

which returns an empty array

if I remove "console.log(data1)" and I modify the code as follow:

```
function getNewArray(val) {
  test2.filter(function(val2){
    if(val.id == val2.id){
       console.log(val2.text);
       }
  });
}
```

I get the desired result.

Why is data1 empty?

Comment: The functions passed to `Array.prototype.filter` should return a boolean that represent for each element of the Array if it should be kept or filtered out. I'm not sure this will fix your problem, but I think what you want is `test2.filter(function(val2) { return val.id == val2.id; })` (or with a lambda `test2.filter(val2 => val.id == val2.id)`)

Comment: it is unclear (for me), what you like to get. please add the wanted result.

Comment: because filter returns a new array, it does not alter the current array. You do not return anything from your function.

Comment: "Why is data1 empty?" Because `getNewArray` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `filter()` method, instead you can use `reduce()` and `forEach()` and return array as result.

```js
var test1 = [{
  id: 1,
  text: 'some text'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'some text 2'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'some text 3'
}, ];

var test2 = [{
  id: 3,
  text: 'some other text 3'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'some other text 2'
}];

function getNewArray(r, val) {
  test2.forEach(function(val2) {
    if (val.id == val2.id) {
      r.push(val2.text);
    }
  });
  return r;
}
var data1 = test1.reduce(getNewArray, []);

console.log(data1);
```